# Does Error Insight have keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: delphi, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-2007

I know I can jump between compiler output messages using ALT + F7/F8.

Are there similar shortcuts to get to the prior/next error detected by Error Insight?

Comment: Since the error insight errors are usually bogus (sarcasm), I would suggest just ignoring them and doing a build, so you can find out if they are real or phantom errors. :-)

Comment: Warren: The problem with compiling is that it can take a while on larger projects. Error Insight is "less acurate", but you don't have to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no shortcut to navigate between the Error Insight.

I haven't found this option in [cnpack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) neither.